# узнать существует ли функция

Tags: php

доброго времени суток. как внутри `B::test();` узнать, что `self::who();` действительно существует? `who` будет определяться динамически, и чуть что не так - вылетит Fatal Error. `get_class_methods()` на `self` не работает (трактует как константу), а других методов я не знаю

```
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public static function test() {
        self::who();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

B::test();
```

Comment: Если ответ помог вам решить вашу задачу, вы можете отметить его как верный (зеленая галочка под стрелками).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая штука

```
bool method_exists ( mixed $object , string $method_name )
```

Думаю она может помочь!

Comment: а как ею воспользоваться? мне надо написать проверку именно перед тем как вызвать `self::`, а в этой функции он тоже трактуется как константа и всегда ответ flase

Comment: `if(method_exists('B','who')){

}`

Comment: спасибо, думаю мне это подойдёт, но она возвращает true если этот метод где то есть (либо в текущем, либо в `self::`), а можно узнать что он точно есть именно в `self::`?

Comment: Попробуй [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156593/find-out-if-a-method-exists-in-a-static-class) посмотреть